# OIDC Dynamic client registration is error in challenge The Pay was invalid

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

I have Identity Server 4 Application where I have added OpenID Authentication scheme dynamically , where Microsoft , Google and some Other provided is working properly but I am facing an error when the authentication scheme is challenged for BigIP SSO I am getting this error.

```
2020-09-18 06:46:57.107 +00:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: susplk was challenged.
   2020-09-18 06:46:59.453 +00:00 [ERR] Exception occurred while processing message.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The payload was invalid.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.CbcAuthenticatedEncryptor.DecryptImpl(Byte* pbCiphertext, UInt32 cbCiphertext, Byte* pbAdditionalAuthenticatedData, UInt32 cbAdditionalAuthenticatedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.Internal.CngAuthenticatedEncryptorBase.Decrypt(ArraySegment`1 ciphertext, ArraySegment`1 additionalAuthenticatedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.DataProtectionCommonExtensions.Unprotect(IDataProtector protector, String protectedData)
   at IdentityServer4.Infrastructure.DistributedCacheStateDataFormatter.Unprotect(String protectedText, String purpose)
   at IdentityServer4.Infrastructure.DistributedCacheStateDataFormatter.Unprotect(String protectedText)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.ReadPropertiesAndClearState(OpenIdConnectMessage message)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
2020-09-18 06:46:59.487 +00:00 [INF] Error from RemoteAuthentication: The payload was invalid..
```

Comment: It is impossible to know what went wrong. The payload was invalid. You have to make sure  the payload is valid. You have to start diagnosing this at the start where the payload gets created and/or verify you and the sender agree on the encryption/decryption scheme used.

Comment: But sometime its works sometime its not working one question in cache every time I am removing a schema and adding one, is it can be reason for that ?

Comment: If it works sometimes then you need to provide more context when it works and when it doesn't. It feels this is a specific fail scenario that depends on your setup, not on the code used.

Comment: I found an issue that the third party Identity Provider is using SAML 2.0 where I am getting the payload error but how OpenID Connect is register SAML 2.0 user sometime that is working, it's really confusing